# How to use a Bootstrap modal to add fields to a form using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a form on a Bootstrap modal that captures employment history info. I want to be able, when the user clicks save on the modal the data the user just entered, display on a form.

Consider the following:

```
<form name="stuff">
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    add position
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="false">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="false">
                &times;
            </button>
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">add Position</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form name="modal-form" class="form-horizontal">
                <!-- form stuff goes here -->
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                Close
            </button>
            <button type="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                Save
            </button>
        </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->

    <!-- after save button data entered on modal goes here i.e. -->
     <input type="text" disabled name="job_title[] value="Software Developer" />
     <input type="text" disabled name="from[] value="November 2013" />  &ndash; <input type="text" disabled name="to[] value="present" /> <input type="text" disabled name="total experience[] value="2 months" /> 
     <input type="text" disabled name="industries[] value="IT" /> 
</form>
```

What I need is after the user clicks save on the modal it displays in the fields as shown above. Can this be done using jQuery? If not, how can I accomplish this?

I have tried searching the web for clues on how to do this, but I don't think I have the correct key words, because I can't find any thing.

**Just in case the code example in unclear:**
First the user clicks a button to make the modal appear, they then fill out form that is on the modal, and when they click save on the modal, the data entered on the modal displays at the bottom of the form, underneath the button to make the modal appear.

Comment: User enters data on a form inside modal and where is the other form where you want those data to appear?

Comment: @marios the modal is inside that form... it is: `<form name="stuff">` see te last bit of `html` code. that is where the entered modal data displays.

Comment: So user enters data in a form somewhere else and then the modal appears with those data already inserted in the modal's form?

Comment: no.. the user clicks a button to make the modal appear, they then fill out  form that is on the modal,and when they click save on the modal, the data entered on the modal displays at the bottom of the form, underneath the button to make the modal appear.

Comment: made a demo for you, have a look

Comment: glad it worked out for you, what is your second question?

Comment: your second question requires a lot more work, not an easy fix. you'll have to rebuild your form to use array

Comment: lol...Thanks that you where wiling to look at my second question. Could you maybe point me in the right direction to where I could find out how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this demo http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/5Vx8g/
You need to add an ID to that button for jquery to select.

```
id="save"
```

The rest is quite straight forward.

Comment: could I maybe ask you another question that is related to this?

Comment: Thanks. Here it goes: How would I add multiple `"job histories"` to the form, i.e. When a user has added his job details on the modal and clicked save to show the data on the form, he would be able to click the button to display the modal again and he will be able to add a new `'job history'`. and that would display underneath the already added `'job history'` on the form.